# How to create two otherwise identical containers that extend different images

Tags: dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2

# Large number of commands
```

I want to create `Dockerfile-py3` that extends `python:3` instead of `python:2` but is otherwise the same. Aside from

```
FROM python:3

# Copy of large number of commands
```

what solution do I have in order to avoid the redundancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `build-arg` option to `docker build` with `ARG` and `FROM` directive of `Dockerfile` together to get desired result like so:

Example of `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG  REPOSITORY_AND_TAG=python:2.7
FROM ${REPOSITORY_AND_TAG}

# Large number of commands
```

Now, if built without any `build-arg` it will default to `python:2.7` as declared in the `Dockerfile`. But, if built wih `build-arg`, you can choose substitute value like so:

```
docker build --build-arg REPOSITORY_AND_TAG=python:latest -t my-docker-image .
```

In which case it will override default (`python:2.7`) value from the `Dockerfile` and you will end up with `python:latest` instead.

Additional documentation:

- about `ARG` usage in `FROM` directive can be found in [the official Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact)
- about `build-arg` usage [also from the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#use-a-custom-parent-cgroup---cgroup-parent)